# Equivalent of annotation @JsonDeserialize for XML

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, jaxb

I'm looking for an annotation to do the same thing for XML responses as for JSON responses, being to convert a date to milliseconds. For a JSON response I would do it like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateToMillisecsDeserializer.class)
private Long millisecs;
```

And then @Override deserialize in the class DateToMillisecsDeseriliazer to convert the date.

How can I accomplish the same exact thing for a XML response?

Thanks!

Comment: It is roughly equivalent to `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` and `XmlAdapter`,
but with serializing and deserializing done together within the same adapter class.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Why don't you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) annotation for XML
is roughly equivalent to [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html)
and [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) together for JSON.

It refers to an [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) class
which is the equivalent of the [`JsonDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html)
and [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) classes together.

**Example:**

The conversion between XML elements like

```
<date>2018-03-29T20:00:00Z</date>
```

and a `Long` Java field with milliseconds since 1970.0 can be done like this:

```
@XmlElement(name = "date")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateMillisecsAdapter.class)
private Long millisecs;
```

The annotation refers to an adapter class doing the actual conversion.
Method `unmarshal` is for deserializing, and `marshal` for serializing.

```
public class DateMillisecsAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Long> {

    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");

    @Override
    public Long unmarshal(String s) throws Exception {
        if (s == null)
            return null;
        return dateFormat.parse(s).getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Long millisecs) throws Exception {
        if (millisecs == null)
            return null;
        return dateFormat.format(new Date(millisecs));
    }
}
```